# ImportError: cannot import name 'ImpliciteSourceTerm' from 'fipy'

Tags: python-import, importerror

I want to solve the Advection-Diffusion equation with a source term in fipy. For my source term, I consider an input coefficient (inputCoeff) and an output coefficient (outputCoeff). When invoking the source term to be solved implicitly, I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\users\bella.aquapole\discrétisation-equations-mercure\untitled0.py:10
from fipy import ImpliciteSourceTerm

ImportError: cannot import name 'ImpliciteSourceTerm' from 'fipy' (C:\Users\bella.AQUAPOLE\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\fipy_*init*_.py)

I first call the fipy library :

> > > from fipy import*

It does not work, so I try calling the ImpliciteSourceTerm as follows

> > > from fipy import ImpliciteSourceTerm

But still doesn't work

Please, How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.